# -bash: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to process some DNA sequencing data. This was going great until I tried to organize folders on my desktop. Even after changing my interpreter location in PYcharm and making sure I'm in the right directory, it still seems to think my interpreter is inside of a folder that no longer exists? How do I get out of this? How did my interpreter get there in the first place?

```
Abigails-MacBook-Pro:~ Meyer$ python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade cutadapt

Requirement already up-to-date: cutadapt in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (3.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: dnaio~=0.4.2 in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from cutadapt) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: xopen~=1.0.0 in ./Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages (from cutadapt) (1.0.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 20.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Abigails-MacBook-Pro:~ Meyer$ cutadapt

-bash: /usr/local/bin/cutadapt: /Users/Meyer/Desktop/Evernia/cutadapt/venv/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

^^^"/Users/Meyer/Desktop/Evernia/cutadapt/venv/bin/python" This is a directory that I originally made in PYcharm (and to be honest, at the time I had no idea what I was doing). Now that I have tried to create a more organized folder in my Desktop to process much more data, I still appear to be stuck in a folder that no longer exists.

Please help me get my interpreter up and running again!

Comment: It appears your terminal has an activated virtualenv. What happens if you start a new terminal session?

Comment: Same issue continues to occur.... I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling both Python 3 and PYCharm and the issue is unresolved.

Comment: You can't rename a virtualenv. Just delete it and start over.

Comment: How do I do that? This is what I have tired:

`stp-er-10-129-18-160:~ Meyer$ rm -r /Users/Meyer/Desktop/Evernia/cutadapt/venv/bin/python
rm: /Users/Meyer/Desktop/Evernia/cutadapt/venv/bin/python: No such file or directory`

Comment: Could you create a new venv and activate it? I also don't know how cutadapt is supposed to work, but I'm not sure using `--user`to install was a good idea